# Using multiple sites in Selenium RC with PHPUnit

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I'm trying to automate a user scenario that involves two websites with no common base url. How can I achieve this? Right now I have unsuccessfully tried altering global variables but they are reset for each test.

```
public $check = true;

protected function setUp() {
    $this->setBrowser("*googlechrome");
    if ($this->check==true)
        $this->setBrowserUrl("SITE A");
    else
        $this->setBrowserUrl("SITE B");
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setHost("0.0.0.0");
}

public testA() { //requires SITE A, set check to false }
public testB() { //requires SITE B }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work since `setUp()` is executed **before every** test case is run.

Why not being more explicit about what you're trying to do? Try the following:

```php
private $sites = array('A' => 'a.com', 'B' => 'b.com');

protected function setUp() {
    $this->setBrowser("*googlechrome");
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setHost("0.0.0.0");
}

public function testA() 
{
    $this->useSite('A');
}

public function testB() 
{
    $this->useSite('B');
}

private function useSite($site)
{
    $this->setBrowserUrl($this->sites[$site]);
}
```